# represent array of hashes in csv

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to convert a CSV file into ruby hash. I am handling a nested hash using dots in csv header. For example, `user.name` as CSV header with cell value `"john"` is converted into:

```
{"user" => {"name" => "john"}}
```

How should I represent an array of hash in my CSV? I want a hash like this:

```
{"scores" => [{"maths" => "60"},{"science" => "50"} ]}
```

I do not know what the CSV header/value format should be to get the hash above. Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: If you provide some excerpt from your csv file I am sure people will readily respond.

Comment: Why not just a hash of hashes, e.g. `{"scores" => {"maths" => "60", "science" => "50"} }`? I don't see a need for the extra array.

Comment: Must you use CSV for this? CSV is for transporting simple tabular data between systems that can't talk to each other any other way. JSON would be a much better fit for this structure.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of data you want in each array, you could have a `scores.maths` header and `scores.science` header and then find the same keys when parsing the header row, in this case `scores` and build your array from that.